# Finding the address of first and last byte of a given index within an array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-address

I'm wondering whether my answer to the following question is correct:

Suppose you have an "int" array declared as: int myArray[20]. The first byte in
the array has the address 1010. What are the addresses of the first and last bytes of myArray[13]? The size of int is 4 bytes.

That means that each index within this array takes up 4 bytes correct? If that's the case, myArray[13] would start 4x13 = 52 bytes after myArray[0]? Meaning that the first byte would be located at address 1062 and the last byte would be 1065?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're

```
static_cast<char*>(&myarray[13])
```

and

```
static_cast<char*>(&myarray[14]) - 1
```

no?

Yes, your calculations are correct. Be careful with your assertion that `sizeof(int)` is `4`, though: I couldn't tell whether you were pointing out a proven fact of your platform, or whether you thought this was a universal constant (which it isn't).

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear with what I'm looking for. I was given this question as a thought exercise and I just wanted to confirm whether my answer was correct.

Comment: @trungnt: "Yes, your calculations are correct" doesn't address that?

Comment: It does. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @trungnt: No problem!